# "Should have been us" or "Should have been we"?

Tags: differences, be, copular-verbs, predicate

I understand that "have been" is a form of the linking verb "to be", so it can only take a predicate nominative. But saying "It should've been us" sounds better.

Answer (score -1):

According to the rules, it should be "It should have been **we**." because, as you noted correctly, "to be" is a linking verb.  This has been discussed in many forums everywhere on the internet.  Just google "it is I vs. it is me".

However, "It should have been **we**" sounds wrong to the vast majority of people, so using that form is a bad idea.  If you do it, that will only distract your readers, and you don't want that.

You can either ignore the rule and say "It should have been **us**" (nobody will mind, and frankly, that form is eventually going to become the new right, because that's how languages evolve); or you can use a completely different wording.  For example, turn "**It should have been we/us who were awarded the prize.**" into "**We should have been awarded the prize.**" or "**We were the only ones worthy of the prize.**", and your problem is solved.

My personal advice: if you can say the same thing with fewer words, do it!